# CheckBox RecyclerView auto checked issue. Detailed below

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When I check a box and in recycler view auto-checked after 11- 12 item.  I didn't even clicked that checkbox here is the code.
I think this issue is in holder with the position so I'm only providing holder code because it's confidential.

Adapter holder code:

```
inner class ProductListViewHolder(val itemBinding: SelectProductLayoutBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
    fun bindItems(data: ManufacturingProductItem, position: Int) {
        if (data.name != null)
            itemBinding.userNameTv.text = data.name
        else
            itemBinding.userNameTv.text = ""
        itemBinding.userNameTv.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onProductClickListener(
                data,
                itemBinding.userNameTv.isChecked
            )
        }
    }
}
```

in belove code about pagination of recycler view kindly understand please

```
binding.productRv.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                return
            }
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                if (productAdapter.getProductResponseList.size > 2) {
                    count++
                    productPresenter.getProducts("", count.toString(), true)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: It is just an issue of bindViewHolder because recyclerview loads items as required one by one as you start scrolling and this issue has already been fixed so please check stackoverflow properly.

Comment: You are setting the text for every item. You should also set the state of the checkbox. The item views get recycled ;-) so if you dont set text or checkbox state they keep old text and state.

Comment: This problems been solved

Comment: Solution of this problem is to add this code override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem

It simply need these function to implement

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
```